# MySQL Private Table?

Tags: mysql

I am looking to create a table that has the following characteristics:

1. Do not drop the table if the connection is closed, only drop when user chooses (therefore, I can't use TEMPORARY keyword)
2. Keep the table private to each independent session and do not share between users (the target app is a desktop app, not a web app).  A user session can have multiple MySQL connects and closes before finishing.
3. Use Engine=Memory

A TEMPORARY table is close to what I need, except the table is lost whenever the connection is closed.  This is not desired.

SYNOPSIS: When the users starts my desktop application, I need to create this private table.  The user will interact multiple times with the app and each time I need to open the MySQL connection, read/update the table and then close the connection.  Finally, once the user closes the application, I can drop the table.  All the while, this table is meant for this user and should not be shared or conflict with other users sessions and their own copy of the same table.

This table will need to be related to existing shared tables (e.g. joined).

UPDATE: I will attempt to use a [`Boost.Bimap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html#bimap.preface) to accomplish this in memory.

Comment: I think you need to redesign your solution. Create a session table and a user is given a session key when they open the app. Then they interact with a shared table that has a session key.

Comment: I like how you used an airplane and are trying to turn it into a skateboard. I'd  reconsider explaining what's being done and why you think that MySQL "private" table is a solution (it's obviously not, since the requirement you have is way, way off the charts). This is a classic XY problem and I strongly advise explaining what you're trying to achieve and scrap this "private" table solution.

Comment: You can bundle an SQLite Db with the app to handle these tables. Unless it needs to relate to some of the shared data.

Comment: Good idea pala_, unfortunately, I do need to "join" this data with shared tables.

Comment: @Tobsey, the session table idea is a good one.  I will probably do this OR simply use application memory.  Thanks.

Comment: Why can’t you just lock access to a specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong tool for the job,
try one of these:

1. session storage (client side)
2. memcached (server side)

Comment: I thought I would ask, just in case there were such a thing as a private mysql table.  I will probably have to use application memory to accomplish this.